# How to use iCloud keychain in my app to share values across installs in different devices?

Tags: ios, icloud, keychain

Does apple support syncing Keychain across multiple installs of the same app under the same Apple ID?

I can find documentation about keyChain but is iCloud keychain available to developers? I cannot find any documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - The keychain is user tied though. The iCloud syncing is something the user can choose but you can't be sure this is turned on. Because it's user tied the user have to use the same Apple ID on all the devices and iCloud sync has to be turned on.

As far as I remember you can choose to share the keys you save with other apps made by the same developer.

**Update to answer comment:** Yes - This is seen as a safe way to store information. If I remember correctly the keychain is encrypted while not in use and can only be unlocked (automatically) by the Apple account. Just note that users will be able to see what is stored in their keychain so this is not a place to hide information from the user.

The keychain should be used to store password and other information that should be stored safely but not hidden from the user.

Comment: Gotcha! I guess my question is if it is actually as secure as iCloud keychain? does it encrypt enteries and such...